# Iterate through a dynamic number of for loops (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I am using python to sequence some numbers. I would like to create a function which allows me to input a value (4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc.), create an array of numbers, and rearrange their sequence.

I've added figures which detail how to determine the sequence for value = 4, and 8.

For value = 4 the array (x = [0, 1, 2, 3]) should be split in two ([0,1] and [2,3]) and then combined based on the first number in each array ([0, 2 ,1 ,3]).

[image: Figure with sequence for value = 4]

For value = 8 the array (x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) should be split into two ([0, 1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6, 7]). Both arrays should be split in two again ([0, 1, 2, 3] into [0,1] and [2,3] and [4, 5, 6, 7] into [4,5] and [6,7]). Then the arrays should be combined based on the first number in each array and the sequence of 2nd set of arrays ([0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7]).

[image: Figure for sequence for value = 8]

I don't know how to handle the recursion (dynamically nested for loops). I am trying to loop through each brach that is created by spliting the array. I've looked into itertools and recursion ([Function with varying number of For Loops (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python)), but I could not make it work. Below, I've added code to illustrate my approach thus far.

Any help is much appreciated. I am also open to other ideas to determine the sequence.

I am using python 2.7.6 and numpy.

Code:

```
import numpy
value = 4
a = []
x = numpy.arange(value)
y = numpy.array_split(x, 2)
for i in range(2):
    for j in y:
        a.append(j.tolist()[i])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1, 3]
```

Code:

```
import numpy
value = 8
a = []
x = numpy.arange(value)
y = numpy.array_split(x, 2)
for i in range(2):
    for h in range(2):
        for j in y:
        z = numpy.array_split(j, 2)
                a.append(z[h][i])
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
[0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7]
```

The output for value = 16 should be [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11 ,7 15].

Comment: Do you need a solution in numpy? This could be done in plain python, I think

Comment: I'd say that what you need is to take the binary form of the numbers and sort them antialphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a NumPythonic way using [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and [`reshaping`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)   -

```
def seq_pow2(N):
    shp = 2*np.ones(np.log2(N),dtype=int)
    return np.arange(N).reshape(shp).transpose(np.arange(len(shp))[::-1]).ravel()
```

Please note that `.transpose(np.arange(len(shp))[::-1]` would simplify to `.T`, so we would have a simplified version -

```
def seq_pow2(N):
    shp = 2*np.ones(np.log2(N),dtype=int)
    return np.arange(N).reshape(shp).T.ravel()
```

You can further simplify and replace the transpose altogether by doing the `ravel`/`flattening` in a column-major ordering like in `fortran` with `.ravel('F')` to lead us finally to -

```
def seq_pow2(N):
    shp = 2*np.ones(np.log2(N),dtype=int)
    return np.arange(N).reshape(shp).ravel('F')
```

Sample runs -

```
In [43]: seq_pow2(4)
Out[43]: array([0, 2, 1, 3])

In [44]: seq_pow2(8)
Out[44]: array([0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7])

In [45]: seq_pow2(16)
Out[45]: array([ 0,  8,  4, 12,  2, 10,  6, 14,  1,  9,  5, 13,  3, 11,  7, 15])
```

Answer (score 2):

The python recursive version, for clarity :

```
def rec(n):
    if n==1 : return [0]
    l=[0]*n
    l[::2]=rec(n//2)
    for i in range (0,n,2) : l[i+1]=l[i]+n//2
    return l
```

for

```
In [6]: rec(16)
Out[6]: [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]
```

Or, observing the binary representation of the result, a numpy solution :

```
def rearange(N):
    u=2**arange(N.bit_length()-1)
    v=arange(N)
    bits= u[None,:] & v[:,None]
    return sum(bits*u[::-1],1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to *not* use for loops but to do some array manipulation with numpy.

```
N = 8
pow2 = np.log2(N)
out = np.arange(N).reshape([2]*pow2).transpose(np.arange(pow2)[::-1]).flatten()   

   array([0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7])
```

What this does is it reshapes `x` into a `n`-dimensional array where `n` is the power of 2 that corresponds to the length of `x`. After this reshaping, the length of each dimension is 2. We then reverse all of the dimensions and flatten to get the array you want.

**Edit**

This is a similar approach to [Divakar's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012781/670206), and he ended up doing it much more concisely, but I'll just leave this here for posterity.