# How to control the number of layer in nested for-loop in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list like `alist = [1, 3, 2, 20, 10, 13]`, I wanna write a function `find_group_f`, which can generate all possible combination of elements in `alist` and meanwhile I can dynamically control the number `k` of element in each group. For instance, if the number `k` is `2`, the function is equal to:

```
for e1 in alist:
    for e2 in alist[alist.index(e1)+1:]:
        print (e1, e2)
```

While the number `k` is 3, it would be like:

```
for e1 in alist:
    for e2 in alist[alist.index(e1)+1:]:
        for e3 in alist[alist.index(e2)+1:]:
            print (e1, e2, e3)
```

I wonder how can I implement like this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a stdlib function for that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations.

Comment: Use recursion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python

Answer (score 0):

to quote:

```
function Recurse (y, number) 
   if (number > 1)
      Recurse ( y, number - 1 )
   else
      for x in range (y)
      whatever()
```

Don't actually know how to quote, so here's a link: [Function with varying number of For Loops (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python)