# Number of nested loops by variable

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

I want my program to find the combinations of x integers with values in a range that summed equal a given number.

For example: I want to find the combinations of 3 integers that can have a value between 0 and 2 and that summed equal 5. I can do this by coding:

```
possibilities = []
total = 5
valueRange = 3
for num1 in xrange(valueRange):
    for num2 in xrange(valueRange):
        for num3 in xrange(valueRange):
            if num1 + num2 + num3 == total:
                possibilities.append([num1, num2, num3])
```

I can change the value of the total sum and the range value by changing the variables I created, but **how can I specify the amount of nested loops using a variable?**
Thank you

Comment: Maybe this helps (recursion): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function should help:

```
>>> [values for values in product(range(3), repeat=3) if sum(values) == 5]
[(1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]
```

Seeing that the answer contains anagrams of the same answer, you can reduce the work further by using [itertools.combinations_with_replacement()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
>>> # 4 digits in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] summing to 6
>>> for values in combinations_with_replacement(range(5), 4):
        if sum(values) == 6:
            print(values)

(0, 0, 2, 4)
(0, 0, 3, 3)
(0, 1, 1, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product` instead.

```
for t in itertools.product(xrange(valueRange), n):
    if sum(t) == total:
        possibilities.append(t)
```