# Determine all combinations of flipping a coin without using "itertools.product"

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, lambda, probability, python-itertools

I went through similar posts on the forum but all of them suggest using `itertools.product` but I was wondering if it can be solved without using it.

I want to print all the combinations of outcomes for N flips of a coin. This can be done if N is known in advance. So the number of nested loops will be just N. But if N has to be determined dynamically (`input()` function) then I am stuck in implementing it in code. In plain English it is easy to imagine that the number of for loops is proportional to N, but how do I implement it?  Do I have to use lambdas or recursion? Below is as example code for N = 4.

```
results = ["H", "T"]
outcomes = []
for l1 in results:
    for l2 in results:
        for l3 in results:
            for l4 in results:
                outcomes.append(l1+l2+l3+l4)

for o in outcomes:
    print(o)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I would use recursion.

Comment: It would be great if you could show me how. I can imagine that I need to simulate dynamic creation of for loops but do not know how.

Comment: Sample code for `product` is [available in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (or look at the itertools source).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DIY with generators**

Here's one way to calculate a `product` of lists without using the built-in

```
def product (*iters):
  def loop (prod, first = [], *rest):
    if not rest:
      for x in first:
        yield prod + (x,)
    else:
      for x in first:
        yield from loop (prod + (x,), *rest)
  yield from loop ((), *iters)

for prod in product ("ab", "xyz"):
  print (prod)

# ('a', 'x')
# ('a', 'y')
# ('a', 'z')
# ('b', 'x')
# ('b', 'y')
# ('b', 'z')
```

In python, we can collect the outputs of a generator in a list by using the `list` constructor. Note we can also calculate the product of more than two inputs as seen below

```
print (list (product ("+-", "ab", "xyz")))
# [ ('+', 'a', 'x')
# , ('+', 'a', 'y')
# , ('+', 'a', 'z')
# , ('+', 'b', 'x')
# , ('+', 'b', 'y')
# , ('+', 'b', 'z')
# , ('-', 'a', 'x')
# , ('-', 'a', 'y')
# , ('-', 'a', 'z')
# , ('-', 'b', 'x')
# , ('-', 'b', 'y')
# , ('-', 'b', 'z')
# ]
```

Because `product` accepts a a list of *iterables*, any iterable input can be used in the product. They can even be mixed as demonstrated below

```
print (list (product (['@', '%'], range (2), "xy")))
# [ ('@', 0, 'x')
# , ('@', 0, 'y')
# , ('@', 1, 'x')
# , ('@', 1, 'y')
# , ('%', 0, 'x')
# , ('%', 0, 'y')
# , ('%', 1, 'x')
# , ('%', 1, 'y')
# ]
```

Because `product` is defined as a generator, we are afforded much flexibility even when writing more complex programs. Consider this program that finds right triangles made up whole numbers, a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). Also note that `product` allows you to repeat an iterable as input as see in `product (r, r, r)` below

```
def is_triple (a, b, c):
  return a * a + b * b == c * c

def solver (n):
  r = range (1, n)
  for p in product (r, r, r):
    if is_triple (*p):
      yield p

print (list (solver (20)))
# (3, 4, 5)
# (4, 3, 5)
# (5, 12, 13)
# (6, 8, 10)
# (8, 6, 10)
# (8, 15, 17)
# (9, 12, 15)
# (12, 5, 13)
# (12, 9, 15)
# (15, 8, 17)
```

Implementing your coin tossing program is easy now.

```
def toss_coins (n):
  sides = [ 'H', 'T' ]
  coins = [ sides ] * n
  yield from product (*coins)

print (list (toss_coins (2)))
# [ ('H', 'H'), ('H', 'T'), ('T', 'H'), ('T', 'T') ]

print (list (toss_coins (3)))
# [ ('H', 'H', 'H'), ('H', 'H', 'T'), ('H', 'T', 'H'), ('H', 'T', 'T'), ('T', 'H', 'H'), ('T', 'H', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'H'), ('T', 'T', 'T') ]
```

---

**Without generators**

But generators are a very high-level language feature and we wonder how we could represent `product` using pure recursion. Below `product` is reimplemented without the use of generators and now returns a filled array with all calculated sub-products

```
def map (f, lst):
  if not lst:
    return []
  else:
    first, *rest = lst
    return [ f (first ) ] + map (f, rest)

def flat_map (f, lst):
  if not lst:
    return []
  else:
    first, *rest = lst
    return f (first) + flat_map (f, rest)

def product (*iters):
  def loop (acc, iters):
    if not iters:
      return acc
    else:
      first, *rest = iters
      return flat_map (lambda c: map (lambda x: [x] + c, first), loop (acc, rest))
  return loop ([[]], iters)
```

We can now skip the `yield` and `list` calls in your program

```
def toss_coins (n):
  sides = [ 'H', 'T' ]
  coins = [ sides ] * n
  return product (*coins)

print (toss_coins (2))
# [('H', 'H'), ('H', 'T'), ('T', 'H'), ('T', 'T')]

print (toss_coins (3))
# [('H', 'H', 'H'), ('H', 'H', 'T'), ('H', 'T', 'H'), ('H', 'T', 'T'), ('T', 'H', 'H'), ('T', 'H', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'H'), ('T', 'T', 'T')]
```

Above, we define `map` and `flat_map` with as few dependencies as possible, however there is only *one* subtle distinction in each implementation. Below, we represent each as a *fold* (using `reduce`) allowing us to see the semantic difference more easily. Also note Python includes its own version of `map` and `reduce` (in `functools`) that differ slightly from the versions provided here.

```
def concat (xs, ys):
  return xs + ys

def append (xs, x):
  return xs + [ x ]

def reduce (f, init, lst):
  if not lst:
    return init
  else:
    first, *rest = lst
    return reduce (f, f (init, first), rest)

def map_reduce (m, r):
  return lambda acc, x: r (acc, m (x))

def map (f, lst):
  return reduce (map_reduce (f, append), [], lst)

def flat_map (f, lst):
  return reduce (map_reduce (f, concat), [], lst)

def product (*iters):
  # this stays the same
```

Comment: This works very well and I will mark as the answer, however my mind is stuck in finding a solution using recursion. Is there a way to use the suggested answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python to adapt to my coin flipping problem.

Comment: Sandeep, I included an edit that shows how to write `product` without generators, but note that all solutions here are using recursion.

Answer (score -1):

```
x=int(input("No. of coin: "))
range_lst=[[] for i in range(2**x)]
i=0
while i<x:
    div=2**(x-1-i)
    alt=0
    for j in range(2**x):
        if alt<div:    
            range_lst[j].append("H")
            alt+=1
        else:
            if alt==((div*2)-1):
                alt-=((div*2)-1)
            else:
                alt+=1
            range_lst[j].append("T")
    i+=1
print(range_lst)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).