# Multiple nested loop replacement equivalent in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

For any given n , I need the following to happen.

```
def count(n):
  for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
      for k in range(0,j+1):
        .......
          n nested loops 
             count=count+1 
   return count
```

I would like to know if there is a more concise way of achieving this above code segment.

the code has to return 5,15,35,70 on input of 1,2,3,4 .

Comment: You wrote that there are `n` nested loops. This is not the same `n` as the argument of the function, is it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python)

Comment: syntonym , yes , it the same n passed in the argument

Comment: raj, I had a look at that. That would return 5,25,125 on input of 1,2,3. What I would like is for it to return 5,15,35 for n=1,2,3 . Thanks.

Comment: There should be a closed-form solution that doesn't involve any loops at all.

Comment: Should count in the last line have an argument?

Comment: yes, some sort of a single line statement involving itertools.

Comment: cardamon, no it's not recursive, count that needs to be returned is the count that was incremented after that n th nested loop

Comment: What you want to compute is the binomial coefficient `binomial(n, 4)` (4 being 5–1, from `range(0, 5)`). See https://oeis.org/A000332

Comment: Please don't reuse the name of your function for a local variable in the function, it makes the code harder to read. Do you *have* to do this with nested loops?

Comment: You can use SciPy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561091/4014959) is a simple binomial function that doesn't use any imports.

Comment: Thanks, the binomial function works perfectly for solution i needed.