# Function with varying number of for loops using the arguments in the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly I would like to say that I've read this thread:

[Function with varying number of For Loops (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186518/function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops-python)

And while it does certainly look similar to what I'd like to know, I'm not proficient enough (at all) with recursion to make it work.

If I have the following snippet:

```py
I = ["i" + str(i+1) for i in range(3)]
J = ["j" + str(i+1) for i in range(4)]
K = ["k" + str(i+1) for i in range(2)]
```

Then I can make a function that does something like this:

```py
def f(*Sets):
    size = len(Sets)
    if size == 1:
        for i in Sets[0]:
            print(i)
    elif size == 2:
        for i in Sets[0]:
            for j in Sets[1]:
                print(i,j)
    elif size == 3:
        for i in Sets[0]:
            for j in Sets[1]:
                for k in Sets[2]:
                    print(i,j,k)
```

And when executing, it would produce something like:

```py
>>f(I)
i1
i2
i3

>>f(I,J)
i1,j1
i1,j2
...
i3,j4

>>f(I,J,K)
i1,j1,k1
i1,j1,k2
...
i3,j4,k2
```

The `print` statement is just an example. I would like to actually access elements in a pandas dataframe at the same time as checking the looped variable, or a dictionary, so it would include some command like `print(i,j,k, ":", dictionary[i,j,k])`. I need to access each variable in the loops, that´s what I mean.

This looks to me that could be widely reduced using some kind of recursion. Because if for example I need four lists, I'd have to add another `elif`. But I have not a recursive type of mind, and can't see how to solve it.

Or maybe it cannot be done at all. Not sure anymore of anything :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursion to implement this, but the simplest would be just to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def f(*sets):
    for p in product(*sets):
        # e.g. (1, 3, 5)
        print(*p)

>>> f([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])
1 3 5
1 3 6
1 4 5
1 4 6
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 4 5
2 4 6
```

`product` returns the cartesian product of the input iterables in the form of a lazy iterator over `tuples`.

A simple recursive implementation of the cartesian product would  go along the following lines:

```
def f(*sets):
    if not sets:
        return [[]]
    result = []
    for head in sets[0]:
        for combo in f(*sets[1:]):
            result.append([head] + combo)
    return result

>>> f([1, 2], [3, 4])
[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have no idea how to do this with recursion tho, but this will almost work. I didn't notice, but I failed to emphasize how important would this output format be. Would there be a similar generalization if I want to print the products with a comma between them? Such as : "i1,k1,j1" instead of "i1 k1 j1". I'm using this to automatically generate a pseudo AMPL data transforming function, and that syntax is very picky.

Comment: I added a recursive approach. What you do inside the innermost for-loop is up to you. You have tuples `p`: you don't need to do `print(*p)`, you can also iterate over them, transform them, or do anything you like. For comma-separated output, you can  do `print(','.join(p))`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Now I see it way clearer. The recursive snippet will take a while to understand, but that's how my brain works :P Thanks!

Comment: Recursion takes a bit to wrap the head around, but once it clicks, you'll love it ;)

Comment: Using recursion to create the product seems like a bad idea given that it takes about 10 lines of code to solve this in an interative way...